# What is the difference between enrolment vs commencement

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, difference, synonyms

What is the difference between enrolment vs commencement in an academic context?

Ex:- While in some states and territories children can commence/ enrol preschool before they turn four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In US terminology, "enrollment" is when you formally join a college or school. You do it on the first day, before you start any classes.

"Commencement" is a ceremony in which you receive your diploma or degree at the end of the course. The notion would seem to be that you have graduated and so are beginning your career. You can also use "commence" in its regular meaning of "begin", but it is formal. "Begin" is a better word to use in most contexts

> John will enrol at kindergarten next fall.
>
> The commencement speech was given by the mayor.
>
> I'm going to begin college in October  (or commence college)
>
> In some states, children can begin preschool before they turn four.

Note that in British terminology, "commencement" is not used the same way. We would say "graduation ceremony".

You may also want "apply for a school", "register at a school", or "put his name down for a school"